# Drupal Services add image to node - Image not available

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

i run a headless Drupal project creating nodes with images over smartphone.

This is all working fine but if i want to view the created node there is no image shown up.

If i open the website normally in browser the image shows up as the image styles get created if i request over normal website.

I need a way to create image styles also if i access over API.

Comment: Can you make one http request to the image that has to be created before you request it with your api?

Comment: I could, but in meantime i discovered a module for this purpose. 
It's imageinfo_cache. => https://www.drupal.org/project/imageinfo_cache.

This module creates every image style directly after saving the image. :-)

Unluckily i can't post answers because for some reason i'm blocked ... :-( New to stackoverflow and no idea what i did and how to remove ban...

If I'm able to post answers again i will answer this question in detail and also provide some code examples.